# How to prevent my model from mistaking categorical feature for ordinal feature

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, categorical-encoding

I have tabular data where each group of 100 rows represents a deployment of a specific geometry that has certain features measured. For example, I have 10000 deployments stored in a column called "Dep": an integer that ranges from 1 to 10000. When fitting this data to an xgboost model, the model may mistakenly assume that the deployment numbers have an ordering relationship (e.g., that deployment 1 is less than deployment 2, which is less than deployment 3, and so on). However, this is not the case because all deployments are independent of each other. On the other hand, if I remove the "Dep" column, the model will not be able to differentiate between the different deployment groups and their unique geometries.

I got the idea of one hot encoding of the column dep, but it's useless as the training dataset has 7000 deployments while the test dataset has 3000. If I do a one hot encoding, the shapes will not match (along with a slew of other issues). Better think of another approach.

What is the solution to this issue?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. It seems to me that your issue is not only about this categorical feature, you want the model to understand the particular grouping of multiple rows, right? The model is going to consider each row as an independent instance anyway, so I suspect that this design is not optimal.

Comment: @Erwan That's right, yet I have no idea how to approach this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you still consider one-hot encoding and apply it as follows:

1. Concatenate train and test dataset
2. Apply `pd.get_dummies` setting `sparse = True` to save memory
3. Split train and test datasets

Here is an example of how you can do it: [Example notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/maryiaznak/dealing-with-categorical-data-logreg-rand-forest?scriptVersionId=107132878&cellId=52)

Hope it will help!